# This LL(1) parse table is correct?

Tags: compilation, grammar, context-free-grammar

Given grammar:

```
S -> AB
A -> aA | b
B -> CA
C -> cC | ɛ
```

Is its LL(1) parsing table is this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not entirely correct because of these calculations:

First(S) = First(A) = `{a,b}`
First(A) = `{a,b}`
First(B) = First(C) = `{c,ε}`
First(C) = `{c,ε}`

Considering that the Follow of each non-terminal symbol is the terminal symbol right after:

Follow(S) =`{a,b}`  (if SAB --> AB then SaAB --> aAB or SbB --> bB)

Follow(A) = `{a,c}` (if AaA-->aA and Ab --> b then AaA --> aA or Ab --> b)

Follow(B) = Follow (A) = `{a,c}` (model production A --> aB, which a terminal, and a = ε, then Follow (A) = Follow (B))

Follow(C) =  `{a,b}` (from B-->CA, B-->CaA or B-->Cb)

So the the difference with your parse table, and these calculations, is that in non-terminal B row in columns a and b the values are NULL.

Comment: How is First(B) = First(C) = `{c,ε}` correct? First(C) = `{c,ε}`, yes, but  First(B) = `{a, b, c}`, `c` from the C production, `a, b` from the A one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes it is correct.
First(S) = First(A) = {a,b}
First(A) = {a,b}
First(B) = {a,b,c} 
B->CA and C->cC|ɛ
First(C) = {c,ε} 
so if we put ɛ as a replacement of C in B -> CA, we'll have B -> A, Thus First(B)= First(A) instead of ɛ.
```